# Slice function for C

Tags: c, strings, pointers, reference

I am trying to create a non-generic [`slice`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) function. I want a 'view' not a copy.

The `scan_from` arg is so that successive calls know where to start from:

```c
const char *slice(const char *s,
                  const size_t i,
                  size_t *scan_from) {
  const size_t substr_length = i - *scan_from + 1;
  if (substr_length > 0) {
    char *substr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * substr_length);
    if (substr == NULL) exit(ENOMEM);
    assert(substr_length == snprintf(
                              substr, substr_length + 1,
                              "%.*s", (int)substr_length,
                              s + *scan_from);
    *scan_from = substr_length + i;
    return substr;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Use is for parsing a large `const char*` and labelling/tagging each piece (minimum 1 char), by iterating over each char and seeing if the 'word' is finished, and if so `slice`-ing it out, otherwise keep iterating (`i`) until 'word' is finished or end of `const char*` is reached.

Comment: Hi @AT don't think many people will recommend you `exit()` from a utility function ..

Answer (score 1):

We're missing the necessary `#include` lines for `malloc()`, `exit()`, `assert()` and `snprintf()`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The argument names `s` and `i` don't convey much information - I find it hard to see how this function is to be used (and the lack of unit tests means there's no examples to consult).

We could make all the arguments `const`, I think:

```
const char *slice(const char *const s,
                  const size_t i,
                  size_t *const scan_from)
```

Don't cast the result of `malloc()`, and don't multiply by 1.  But do fix the **bug** of not allocating enough space to write the terminating null character:

```
char *substr = malloc(substr_length + 1);
```

It's good that you check the return value from `malloc` - but it's probably better to return a null pointer (after setting `errno = ENOMEM`) than to exit the program when allocation fails.

The use of `snprintf()` seems to me to be a very long-winded way to write `strncpy(substr, s + *scan_from, substr_length); substr[substr_length] = '\0';`.  The `assert()` doesn't appear to be justified, as there's nothing that guarantees that there are `i` or more characters remaining in the string.  Also, we have functional code within the `assert()` macro invocation - that means that production builds won't call `snprintf()` at all - another **bug**.

Comment: `substr_length` has a `+1` in its definition, doesn't `snprintf` allow me to skip actually copying anything (unlike `strncpy`)? - Good points on the `assert` and `ENOMEM` lines.

Comment: Actually looks like it does copy, to avoid copies I'll need to store the pointer and length in a `struct` and pass that around. Looks like Microsoft already has an open-source cross-platform implementation I can readily use: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c/tree/main/sdk/docs/core#working-with-spans

Comment: There's an off-by-one somewhere with `substr_length`; I may have misidentified which line needs to change.  Certainly `malloc(substr_length)` is inconsistent with `snprintf(substr, substr_length+1, …)`, and running under Valgrind should identify that particular overrun.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about skipping copying - `snprintf(NULL, size, …)` returns the size that would be used (in this case, like a hypothetical `strnlen()` function), but you need to copy the characters to `substr` at some point, don't you?

Answer (score -1):

Following from [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/275859/29485) good review.

**Goal unclear**

OP has "I want a 'view' not a copy.", yet uses `malloc` to make a copy.

**Lacking documentation**

Poor for code to have a buried memory allocation yet does not advise that the caller should free it.

"to create a non-generic slice function. I want ....", "The scan_from arg is ... " and "Use is for ..." deserve to be in code as a comment and/or code should be clear enough to explain itself.

The parameters names `s, i` in `const char *slice(const char *s, const size_t i, size_t *scan_from)` are not informative enough.

Document at a high level as if caller has access to the function declaration and not the definition.  (in the .h file)

**Array or string?**

It appears that the function is to slice an *array* of `char`.  Yet `"%.*s"` terminates early if a *null character* is found.  This is a bug for an array function.

**A helper function that exits!?**

`exit(ENOMEM)` is surprising and undocumented in function description.  [@Mr R](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275846/slice-function-for-c/275883#comment546274_275846) Further, `ENOMEM` is not part of the standard C lib and reduces portability.

```
// if (substr == NULL) exit(ENOMEM);
if (substr == NULL) return NULL;
```

**Avoid function change in non-debug mode**

Do not bury important functionality in an `assert()`.

```
// assert(substr_length == snprintf(substr, substr_length + 1,
//    "%.*s", (int)substr_length, s + *scan_from);

int len = snprintf(substr, substr_length + 1, "%.*s", 
    (int)substr_length, s + *scan_from);
assert(len >= 0 && (unsigned) len == substr_length);
```

**Formatting**

Use an auto formatter.

**Allocate to the referenced object**

Easier to code right, review and maintain.  Cast not needed.

```
// char *substr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * substr_length);
char *substr = malloc(sizeof substr[0] * substr_length);
```

**Be prepared for `i < *scan_from`**

Recall `size_t` is an *unsigned* type and `i - *scan_from` can become a large value near `SIZE_MAX`.

Robust code parameter validation takes into account `i, *scan_from` could independently be any value [0 ... `SIZE_MAX`].

```
// const size_t substr_length = i - *scan_from + 1;
// if (substr_length > 0) {

if (i >= *scan_from) {
  const size_t substr_length = i - *scan_from + 1;
```

**`const` return?**

I'd expect a return types `char *` and not `const char *` as code is providing a allocated buffer for caller's use.

**Bug**

In extreme use `(int)substr_length` fails when `substr_length > INT_MAX`. Function description would mention that.  Better code would work for all `substr_length`.  Consider `memcpy()` instead for an array function.

Comment: @Toby Speigh Your DV?